# Defining formulas for first-order linear differential equations.

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, notation

When defining the formulas for the first-order linear differentiable functions we are necessitated to define a equation that satisfies $u'(x)$ = $u(x)p(x)$ so then the product rule can be applied. And as may be noted, the resultant equation for $u(x)$ is can be well defined through the following steps.

\begin{aligned}
\frac{\mu^{\prime}(x)}{\mu(x)} & =p(x) \\
\int \frac{\mu^{\prime}(x)}{\mu(x)} d x & =\int p(x) d x \\
\ln |\mu(x)| & =\int p(x) d x+C \\
e^{\ln |\mu(x)|} & =e^{\int p(x) d x+C} \\
|\mu(x)| & =C_1 e^{\int p(x) d x} \\
\mu(x) & =C_2 e^{\int p(x) d x} .
\end{aligned}

However, in practice when using these equations, why do we omit $C_2$? why does this not seem to affect our results? In essense, why are we only defining $u(x)$ as $\mu(x)=e^{\int p(x) d x}$ when performing our calculations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you're solving first-order linear ODE, or every ODE (or even PDE) that can be solved by using **integration factor**, you're looking for a $\mu$ that multiplying the differential equation by this factor make it possible for integration! so you actually multiply **both side** of equation by $\mu$. it means every non-zero constant factor of $\mu$ like $\mu'=c\mu$ would also works for equation, since it would be **cancel out later from both side**.

Comment: I see what you mean when you have $u(x)y =$ some equation + $c$ which implies that when you divide by sides by $u(x)$ you will have the reciprocal of $u$ times $C$.

Answer (score 0):

The constant is implicit in the indefinite integral notation, so need not be written explicitly. Remember $\int f(x)dx$ signifies all the antiderivatives of $f$ (each one only differing by a constant).

Comment: In this instance, however. Unless an initial value is given for our y, we seek to find the general solution, so explicitly defining stating C is needed. The issue was that I did not look into the entire process and I did not see that the final C value in the equation for y was actually accounting for all the C values before it.